# Excel VBA How to prevent user from hitting cancel in msoFileDialogSaveAs

Tags: vba, excel, if-statement, filedialog

I am very new to VBA and I am creating a template for my boss. I want to force users to "save as" so that they don't overwrite the template. In other words, I'd like to disable the cancel button when the save as dialog box pops up.

Here is my code:

```
Dim fPth As Object
Set fPth = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogSaveAs)

With fPth
    .InitialFileName = CTAPath
    .InitialFileName = CTAName & "_CAP DATA"
    .Title = "Save with your CTA file"
    .InitialView = msoFileDialogViewList
    .FilterIndex = 2
    If .Show = -1 Then
        .Execute

    End If
End With
```

I'm thinking I should create an ELSE statement within the IF statement but I can't figure out what it should be. I've tried searching and I'm not coming up with any solutions.

Thank you!

Comment: You know, user can overwrite the existing file using the "Save As" dialog too!

Comment: Put your template in a ReadOnly directory and let users open it from there, you can't force users when VBA is disabled

Comment: Excellent idea - protect the file with the settings meant to protect the file, rather than trying to outsmart the users. (Users are really good at finding a way around your best planning.)  Although I was also wondering **why do you give the user a dialog box at all**, instead of saving the file where/how you want it to be saved programmatically, and then *informing* the user that the file has been saved (instead of *asking*).  Are you aware that you can save without using the `Save As` Dialog at all?

Comment: Grant the template specific permissions to avoid unautorized users to writing it. Its not a coding issue (should not be), I would go to other [Super user](https://superuser.com/) site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure you're able to disable `Cancel` button, but there is workaround...

You can loop `.Show` method till user hits `Save` button ;)

For example:

```
Sub PreventCancel()

Dim fPth As Object
Set fPth = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogSaveAs)
Dim result As Variant

With fPth
    .InitialFileName = CTAPath
    .InitialFileName = CTAName & "_CAP DATA"
    .Title = "Save with your CTA file"
    .InitialView = msoFileDialogViewList
    .FilterIndex = 2
    Do
        result = .Show
    Loop While result <> True
   .Execute
End With

End Sub
```

**[EDIT]**

I'd suggest to use [Application.GetSaveAsFilename Method (Excel)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/application-getsaveasfilename-method-excel) instead of `FileDialog`, because it gives you more control over it.

Please, read valuable comments to your question also.

Comment: I think you meant the "save" button, not the cancel button.

Comment: Just a suggestion: if the goal is to prevent the file from being overwritten, it could be a good idea to not only make sure that the user doesn't click `cancel`, but also that the filename they select is **not the existing filename**.  (They can easily still overwrite a file through the Save As dialog!)

Comment: @ashleedawg, good idea. I've mentioned already that OP needs to read valuable comments to he's question.

Answer (score 2):

That's not the way to do this: if the users choose the file itself in the "Save as" filelist, you might end up in the same situation.
I'd advise you to make the file read-only, so nobody can change or overwrite it.